# VS Code won't autosuggest when importing a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

(Currently using VS Code on macOS Monterey, mostly for React and JavaScript.)

When I used to import a component at the top of my file, Vs Code would suggest the path of the file. I would simply press enter or click on the suggestion and VS Code would fill in the rest. Seems to me like a standard feature of VS Code, and I've grown pretty accustomed to it.

Now, it doesn't suggest anything. I'll type out a file that exists in the project, and nothing appears. I've tried it with several projects, and none of them suggest anything anymore — when just last week it was working fine.

[trying to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcvDW.png)

One thing... I have a lingering suspicion that it's from doing this:

```
npm i @types/react -g
```

A friend recommended I add it. With it, you can declare a component in your project and VS Code will auto import it. Really, it's the only thing I can remember changing since this strange behavior with VS Code started, but I'm not positive. Just a suspicion. I've tried to remove it, but it didn't fix anything.

I've done a bunch of stuff found on stackoverflow already with no improvements:

- adding to setting.json, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68097197/auto-import-visual-studio-code-not-working-in-jsx), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964222/vscode-auto-import-components-suggestion-not-working-in-react-vscode-version-1)
- even [deleted VS Code w/ extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vs-code-on-mac)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637561/auto-import-of-react-components-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @Orion447 So I have to add a jsconfig.json to every new project I work on? Doesn't seem practical...

Comment: Oh I'm not sure, this question just seemed like a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [How do I tell typescript/tsconfig.json to use the globally installed node package?](/q/59871695)